# Android Back Key Error

Tags: android, api, nullpointerexception

Anytime I press the Back Key, my application crashes. I have tried to different ways, and they both crash throwing a NullPointerException.... any ideas?

Way 1:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  // Check if the key event was the BACK key and if there's history
  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
      myWebView.goBack();
      return true;
  }
  // If it wasn't the BACK key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
  // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Way 2:

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
      myWebView.goBack();
      return;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at com.meanwhileinwv.android.MNWVShow.onBackPressed(MNWVShow.java:27)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:1983)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1518)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2163)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1747)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2702)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2677)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1965)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-19 20:13:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1963):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from your crash? What line is the NullPointerException happening on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get the stack trace you are getting from the code you've shared is for `myWebView` to be `null` when `myWebView.goBack()` is called. To prove this to yourself, modify your `onBackPressed()`:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (myWebView != null) {
        myWebView.goBack();
    }
}
```

The exception should go away. (Though, obviously, you still won't get any back behavior occurring.)

Possible causes:

- `myWebView` is not a member variable in your class. You may have declared and set it in another method, which means it's not in scope of onBackPressed.
- `myWebView` isn't the actual name of the variable that refers to your WebView
- `myWebView` used to refer to your WebView but at some point was set to `null` again
- The code that you think is pointing `myWebView` to your `WebView` is actually setting to `null`. For instance, a `findViewById` call that is not actually finding the `WebView` because you've specified the wrong ID will return `null`.
- etc.

If you're still stuck, post the code where `myWebView` is declared and where it is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The only common point in that code is myWebView. Have you ensured it's not null?

Comment: myWebView is displaying a site, so it's not null. AND it works in a similar Activity.

Comment: The WebView itself can be working properly, but the Activity's reference to it could still be null. Have you verified the contents by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: How would I go about verifying the content?

Comment: if (myWebView == null) { throw new NullPointerException("myWebView")}

Comment: you can just do a check before performing myWebview.goBack() like 
if(myWebView != null). If you no longer get the exception after you put that check in, then you have a null webview